# Parsing XML API Result Using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I am using Element Tree to parse the following result of an API call.

```
<response status="success" code="19">
<result total-count="1" count="1">
    <users>
        <entry name="admin">
            <phash>$$$$$</phash>
            <permissions>
                <role-based>
                    <superuser>yes</superuser>
                </role-based>
            </permissions>
        </entry>
        <entry name="tester">
            <permissions>
                <role-based>
                    <superuser>yes</superuser>
                </role-based>
            </permissions>
            <phash>$$$$$</phash>
        </entry>
    </users>
</result>
```

I would like to simply print the username which is an attribute of entry. I am using the following code to parse this.

```
def BP01002(ip, apikey):
  xpath = "/config/mgt-config/users"
  rulequery = {'type': 'config', 'action': 'get', 'key': apikey, 'xpath': xpath}
  rrule = requests.get('https://' + ip + '/api', params = rulequery, verify=False)
  rresp = ET.fromstring(rrule.text)
  user = rresp.findall("./result/users")
  print user
```

If I just execute a print user I get the following response, which I would expect.

```
[<Element entry at 6ffff0948c0>, <Element entry at 6ffff094a28>]
```

If i try to print the text of the result with a user.text or a user.attrib I get the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How can I pull just the entry name text data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findall returns a list. If you want to print the element.text, you would need something like

```
[u.text for u in rresp.findall('users')]
```

However, this is only going to print the newline after `<users>`.
I suspect, what you probably want is something more like

```
>>> [e.attrib for e in rresp.findall('users/entry')]
[{'name': 'admin'}, {'name': 'tester'}]
```

Just to be complete, element.text returns the text inside the open and close tags of a text node element, like

```
<element>sometext</element>
```

or "sometext". If your element is not a text node, it will return the newline or whatever is between the element and the next node.

```
<element>
    <child>
    </child>
</element>
```

In the above example, for node child or element, the text would return a newline.